# Janus GridEX crashes when i drag a grouping column out of Janus Control

Tags: c#, wpf, janus, gridex

I have a Janus Grid with a bunch of columns. I currently have group by functionality that lets me group my grid based on any column just by dragging the column to the top.

Say I group by the column "Country". Now i remove the column "Country" from the view. At this point i still have the grid grouped by "Country". Now when i drag the group by Country outside the grid to remove the grouping my application crashes.

I get the following crash log.

Please Help. Janus documentation sucks btw.

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Janus.Data.JanusCollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Janus.Data.JanusGroupCollectionBase.BaseGet(Int32 index)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable.f(Graphics , GridEXRow , JanusRow , GridEXFormatStyle , Int32 )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.a(Graphics , Boolean )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.a(Graphics )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.t()
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.GetCellBounds(Int32 rowPosition, GridEXColumn column)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.bz()
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.Data.JNSAB.OnSuspendRowManagerIndex()
   at Janus.Data.JanusRowManager.SuspendIndex()
   at Janus.Data.DataSourceManager.a(JanusTableBase )
   at Janus.Data.JanusTableBase.OnGroupSettingsChanged(CollectionChangeType change, JanusGroupBase group)
   at Janus.Data.JanusTableBase.Janus.Data.ICollectionOwner.OnCollectionChanged(Object collection, CollectionChangeType change, Object item)
   at Janus.Data.JanusCollectionBase.OnRemoveComplete(Int32 index, Object value)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXGroupCollection.OnRemoveComplete(Int32 index, Object value)
   at Janus.Data.JanusCollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at Janus.Data.JanusCollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.Remove(Object value)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXGroupCollection.Remove(GridEXGroup group)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.c(Boolean )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with the new version of Janus.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    gdRPFecha.RootTable.Groups.Clear();
}
catch (Exception error)
{
}
```

Works for me

Comment: Please consider elaborating your question, describing why it solves the issue.